# Running a Python script in a Makefile

Tags: python, python-2.7, makefile

I have a Python script (scr1.py) that calls another Python script (scr2.py) and they both on the same path. When I open CMD and run scr1.py everything works perfectly.

I want to run scr1.py inside a Makefile that is NOT on the same path as the scripts. The scr1.py is executing but fail on calling scr2.py. I think the problem is that scr1.py searches the Makefile directory instead of the scripts directory.
How can I fix it?

The code:

```
import os
import scr2
fileinfo = os.stat('scr2.py')

if os.path.isfile("infofile.txt"):          
    file=open("infofile.txt",'r')       
    lm = file.read()
    file.close()
    if lm == str(fileinfo.st_mtime): 
        #Do_Something
    else:
        scr2
else:
    scr2
    file = open("infofile.txt",'w')
```

OK, I just fount another problem.
When you import another file, it runs this file IN THE IMPORT LINE!
It means that this isn't the right way to import a file, unless you use the import line where you want to run the script, but it is so ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both files are in same directory, how about just appending the current working directory path before second file name ?

```
import os
import scr2
fileinfo = os.stat( os.getcwd() + '/scr2.py')

if os.path.isfile("infofile.txt"):          
    file=open("infofile.txt",'r')       
    lm = file.read()
    file.close()
    if lm == str(fileinfo.st_mtime): 
        #Do_Something
    else:
        scrcompile                                  
else:
    scrcompile                      
    file = open("infofile.txt",'w')
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I see now that I made a mistake. I changed the names of the scripts so it would be easier to understand. Unfortunately I was in a big hurry so I forgot to check that all of them were changed.

By scrcompile I mean scr2. that's the part that wont run.

Comment: After a little modifications, I've manage to get this to work.
The os.getcwd() did the work.